# This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration

Tags: paypal

I have installed opencart and now looking to enable paypal pro services for UK, i am newby to paypal, do i need to register for payflow services on https://manager.paypal.com ?
if not then what information should i place so that i can get out of the following error:

This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to sign up for PayPal Website Payments Pro at https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/website-payments-pro

Note however, that Website Payments Pro is only available in the US, UK and Canada at the moment as far as I know.

If you can't (or don't want to) sign up for Website Payments Pro, you cannot use the 'Pro' module in OpenCart, and you'll have to use PayPal Website Payments Standard or PayPal Express Checkout instead (these both include a redirect to the PayPal website).